# Karate assertion

Tags: conditional-statements, karate, assertion

Need to write two kind of assertions for the code below

1. if  “pay_eligible": false, then assert ineligibility is not null

“payment_data: {
“pay_details": {
“pay_eligible": false,
"ineligibility: “balance”
}
}

2. if pay eligible is true then ineligibility should not be populated

“payment_data: {
“pay_details": {
“pay_eligible": true,
}
}

```
* if ('pay_eligible' = false) karate.assert('ineligibility': '#notnull')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I strongly discourage "dynamic" tests like this, refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54126724/143475 - in other words, write each scenario so that you know exactly what the response should be and "hard code" it. Trust me on this, it will save you a lot of pain in the long run.

That said, here is just one way to achieve what you want. More tips can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50350442/143475

```
* def response = { pay_details: { pay_eligible: false, ineligibility: 'balance' } }
* def expected = { pay_details: { pay_eligible: '#boolean' } }
* expected.pay_details.ineligibility = response.pay_details.pay_eligible ? '#notpresent' : '#string'
* match response == expected
```

You might be able to reduce this further, but I leave it for you as an exercise: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70055035/143475