# Can a match or comparison of 2 arrays be based on key set

Tags: karate

When trying to compare 2 different responses (source and actual) a conversion happens in our code that we need to account for and I am unsure how to do it.

Array1 = ["NEVER-CONNECTED","ACTIVE","NEVER-CONNECTED"]
Array2 = ["N","A","N"]

While these are these same, a simple match does not work.  Is it possible to convert one of the arrays based on a key of sort?
`convert A to ACTIVE, N to NEVER-CONNECTED, D to DISCONNECTEd. All other values are stored as is`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
* def lookup = { N: 'NEVER-CONNECTED', A: 'ACTIVE' }
* def expected = ["NEVER-CONNECTED", "ACTIVE", "NEVER-CONNECTED"] 
* def response = ['N', 'A', 'N'] 
* def converted = response.map(x => lookup[x])
* match converted == expected
```

And the "lookup" approach can scale to any number of key-value pairs. More explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59162760/143475

Answer (score 1):

This worked, but I am unsure if this is the most elegant way
$aResponse.serviceabilities[*].connectionStatusCode is:   ["N","A","N"]
$bResponse.serviceabilities[*].connectionStatus is:    ["NEVER-CONNECTED","ACTIVE","NEVER-CONNECTED"]

```
    # Translation - convert A to ACTIVE, N to NEVER-CONNECTED, D to DISCONNECTEd. All other values are stored as is
    * def connectionStatusCode = $aResponse.serviceabilities[*].connectionStatusCode
    * if (printDebug) { karate.logger.debug('connectionStatusCode is:  ', connectionStatusCode); }
    * def conversion =
    """
    function(x){
      var value = '';
      karate.log('x: ', x);
      if (x == 'A') {value = 'ACTIVE'}
      else if (x == 'D') {value = 'DISCONNECTEd'}
      else if (x == 'N') {value = 'NEVER-CONNECTED'}
      else {value = x}
      return value;
      }
    """
    * def convertedConnectionStatusCode = karate.map(connectionStatusCode, conversion)
    * match bResponse.serviceabilities[*].connectionStatus == convertedConnectionStatusCode
```