# Data template with embedded expression to match mutiple string values

Tags: karate

With a JSON data that has a key, e.g. "gender", that can have multiple possible valid values, how can this be tested using a data-drive JSON file with embedded expressions.

For example, the JSON file can have:

```
{
  "name": "Joe Jones",
  "gender": "male"
}
```

or

```
{
  "name": "Mary Jones",
  "gender": "female"
}
```

I want to check that the gender value is valid, i.e. either "male" or "female".

I've tried this (and variants of it) but can't get it to work (or figure out the correct syntax):

```
{
  "name": "#string",
  "gender": "# _ ^* ['male','female']"
}
```

but that makes it think that it's trying to match a string (from the original JSON) to an array. I just need to make sure the string value matched one (any) of the elements from the array, though it is not an array element itself.

Answer (score 1):

I was experimenting and found this as the answer:

```
  "gender": "##regex(male|female)"
```

I also noticed that if I put whitespace around each of the possible values it wouldn't work; strange.

Comment: yes that will work for simple cases. one recommendation I have is to not try to stuff all validations into a single JSON, there is nothing wrong with splitting variables into multiple lines and then reading a JSON

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
* def genders = ['male', 'female']
* def response = { "name": "John", "gender": "male" }
* match response == { name: '#string', gender: '#? genders.includes(_)' }
```

Also refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77851131/143475

Comment: But that isn’t using the data driven approach with embedded expressions

Comment: @JohnSilva sorry then I give up. maybe someone else here can give you a better solution. also do a search, all the best: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5D+data+driven+embedded

Comment: I was experimenting and found this as the answer:


```JSON
 "gender": "##regex(male|female)"
```