How to match that the API response has one of the possible value using Karate?
I have a response which I would like to validate in such a way that a particular attribute in this case capital may contain any of the following value {"BOM", "DEL", "BLR"}
Here is my example -
* def cityDetails =
"""
[
 {
  "state":"KA",
  "capital":"BLR",
  "population":"1M"
 },
 {
  "state":"MH",
  "capital":"BOM",
  "population":"1.5M"
 }
]
"""

When I used the following match statement -
* match each cityDetails[*].capital contains any ['BOM', 'DEL', 'BLR']

It does not give me the desired assertion. What possible mistake I may be making here? Please guide.

Personally, I discorage such "clever" tests, explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78131074/143475
But if you insist, refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/77851131/143475
Here's one way to do it - it may not be the best way but will just give you ideas:
* def data = ['BLR', 'BOM', 'DEL']
* def capitals = cityDetails.map(x => x.capital)
* def valid = capitals.filter(x => data.includes(x))
* match capitals == valid


I used this concept and does work but I guess it is only filtering the unique values and removes and duplicate entry. For example if in my original example if there is one more object whose value is same as one of the defined value, it does not add. Possibly it is taking as a Set?

@u238825 it depends. as far as I know filter() should not create a set. can you open a new question with a simple example?

Remove each and try the assertion.
* match cityDetails[*].capital contains any ['BOM', 'DEL', 'BLR']


I was able to also achieve this problem with the following way -
* def hasExpectedCity = function(m) {return m == 'BOM' || m == 'DEL' || m == 'BLR'}
* mach each cityDetails[*].capital == '#? hasExpectedCity(_)'

This to me made more sense, as it was able to solve two of my underlying issues -
1- It fails if anything else is occured in the result, example the assertion will fail if the response has a city as 'HYD'.
2- It also resolved my issue if certain city were repeating.
Hope this helps someone too.
