# How can I implement complex conditional logic for feature files in Karate?

Tags: karate

I am building a testing suite using Karate Framework that has a very specific requirement.

I have two feature files, each with a different API call in them. Depending on a value in my test data that I am passing in from the 'Examples' section, I will need to call either one of those two feature files, or both. Once the appropriate feature file(s) are called, I want to store the JSON responses from the API calls into a variable.

One feature file is titled xApiTest.feature, and another is titled yApiTest.feature.

I am currently attempting this solution with the following:

```
   And def jsonResponses = {}

   And def productTypeDetector =
   """
    ProductType == 'x' ? 'xApiTest.feature' :
    ProductType == 'y' ? 'yApiTest.feature' :
    ProductType == 'Both' ? ['xApiTest.feature', 'yApiTest.feature'] : null

  """
   And def jsonResponses = call read(productTypeDetector) {'myParam': myParam}
```

Would this be the appropriate solution, using a JS function? Or is there a better approach? I looked at the conditional logic section of the documentation, but was unsure if I could incorporate that type of logic with these requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Personal opinion - these don't belong in tests, and will make it hard for future team members to understand and maintain your tests. Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54126724/143475

Now that you have been warned, there are ways to do complex logic, and you are right - you can use JS. Also read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50350442/143475

Note that JSON can be very effectively used as a "lookup table": https://stackoverflow.com/a/59162760/143475

Comment: I normally would not take the approach with complex logic. It is required in my testing because if the product type is 'Both', I will need to call the two API's, concatenate the result, and compare it to another API. The API's will be generating PDF's. So one API is built to generate two id cards on a single PDF, but the two other API's that will be concatenated are built to only generate a single id card. I'm using a PDF to String conversion function and some other complex logic to achieve this. But I was struggling with the product type detection.

Comment: ok, I hope you got a solution, all the best

Comment: Still trying with a JS function in my original post. Not having the best luck. Thanks for the resources though

Comment: @impend yes, you seem to have a non-typical case. I normally don't recommend falling back to Java, but it can help you move a bunch of logic out of a feature file: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#calling-java